# These 2 windows.onscroll javascript codes don't work together

Tags: javascript

I am not a javascript expert. I have these two codes that don't work simultaneously. I don't know why and i ask you where could be the issue?

```js
// This is the first part 

//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("scrollToTop");
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function toTopFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};


// This is the second part   

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

Thanks to anyone

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors and [edit] your question and provide a [mre], along with your _desired_ results and your _actual_ results, including all _errors_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you assign to `window.onscroll` it replaces the previous assignment.

If you want multiple event listeners, use `addEventListener()`.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
```

or call both functions in a single handler:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction();
    myFunction();
};
```